# How to control validation data for Federated framework

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I'm trying to specify the validation data that is passed through the federated framework to each client to train/validation on. I know that tensorflow-federated takes random sample of each client's dataset and validate on it. But if my data (within a subset) is very correlated, how can I specify (in the TFF framework) the validation data-set to each client?
Do you think shuffling the data makes sense here? (e.g. using: 
`DS.repeat(FL_rpt).shuffle(FL_shuf).batch(FL_batch)`) 
If so, any recommendation on the shuffle_buffer size?

In keras training, we have the following to train the model on Set A and validate the training on set B:

```
model.fit(InA,OutA, validation_data=(In_valid_B,Out_valid_B),batch_size=100,epochs=100)
```

How can we do the same with the federated framework?

Answer (score 1):

This could probably be written in the outer Python loop during simulation. The current APIs don't have a notion of both evaluation and training inside a single round.

If using the simulation datasets included in TFF (e.g. those under [`tff.simulation.datasets`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/datasets)), they include a train/test split that makes this easy. Each returns a 2-tuple of [tff.simulation.ClientData](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/ClientData) objects, a test and a train `ClientData`. Both test and train have the same `ClientData.client_id` lists, but the `tf.data.Dataset` returned by `create_tf_dataset_for_client(client_id)` will have a disjoint set of examples.

In other words, the train and test split is over user examples, *not* over users.

A federated training and federated evaluation loop might look like:

```py
train_data, test_data = tff.simulation.datasets.shakespeare.load_data()

federated_average = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn, ...)
federated_eval = tff.learning.build_federated_evaluation(model_fn)

state = federated_average.initialize()

for _ in range(NUM_ROUNDS):
  participating_clients = numpy.random.choice(train_data.client_ids, size=5)

  # Run a training pass
  clients_train_datasets = [
    train_data.create_tf_dataset_for_client(c) for c in participating_clients
  ]
  state, train_metrics = federated_average.next(state, client_train_datasets)

  # Run an evaluation pass
  client_eval_datasets = [
    test_data.create_tf_dataset_for_client(c) for c in participating_clients
  ]
  eval_metrics = federated_eval(state.model, client_eval_datasets)
```